# Figure out root cause for rust error message on zsh login

Tags: rust, zsh, oh-my-zsh

When I open a new zsh terminal window, I get the following message shown:

```
/proc/self/fd/14:2: bad pattern: ^[[1
thread 'main' panicked at 'failed printing to stdout: Broken pipe (os error 32)', library/std/src/io/stdio.rs:1009:9
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

How can I figure out which command is causing this problem? I have a few plugins installed like oh-my-zsh, but also sdkman, etc.

If I enable `RUST_BACKTRACE=full`,  I get the complete stacktrace inside RUST libraries, but still no pointer who called the RUST libraries.

Comment: Without seeing your config files, the easiest way to narrow it down is to disable plugins one by one until the problem goes away.

Comment: `zsh -x -l -i` and read the trace logs to see which command is causing the problem. Maybe set PS4 so you get a source file and line number for each line of the log output.

Comment: BTW, I'd argue that this is a better question for [unix.se]; diagnosing where in one's dotfiles an error message is coming from is a task that folks who don't do software development at all can need to accomplish from time to time.

Comment: What is the complete stacktrace? What is your full list of plugins?

Comment: It turned out to be sdkman plugin. Nevertheless, I was more looking for a general approach to list the last command executed before an error occurred...